# onsubmit form values to php sql request

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, web

I have many input values from a form, and I would like to push them to PHP code using ajax code. Here's an example of what i'm trying to do. I have test1 and test2 that i want to keep track when user press search button.

Right now it only get the value of test1 "getResults(this.test1.value)" I would like to know how to get the test2 value using the same method.

```
<form name="input" action="" method="" onsubmit="getResults(this.test1.value); return false;">

  <input type="text" name="test1">

<select id="test2" name="test2">
  <option value="">Make a choice ...</option>
  <option value="c1">choice 1</option>
  <option value="c2">choice 2</option>
  <option value="c3">choice 3</option>
</select>    


<input type="submit" value="Search">

</form>

<div id="here"><b></b></div>
```

The getresults method, right now it only support one string, how can I add more arguments ?

```
 function getResults(str)
 {
 if (str=="")
   {
   document.getElementById("here").innerHTML="";
   return;
   } 
 else (window.XMLHttpRequest)
   {
   xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
   {
   if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
     {
     document.getElementById("here").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
     }
   }
 xmlhttp.open("GET","info.php?q="+str,true);
 xmlhttp.send();
 }
```

and finaly and more importantly how can I retreive values from info.php ? Thanks a lot

```
<?php
$test1 = $_GET['test1'];
echo "$test1";

$test2 = $_POST["test2"];
echo "$test2";
?>
```

Comment: Did you try doing it the exact same way for the other input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to pass argument to the function. We can grab the form fields value there.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getResults()
        {
            var xmlhttp;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else
            {// code for IE6, IE5
              xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
              if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                    document.getElementById("here").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }

            var data = "test1="+document.getElementById("test1").value+"&test2="+document.getElementById("test2").value;

            xmlhttp.open("POST","info.php",true);
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            xmlhttp.send(data);
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="input" action="" method="" onsubmit="getResults(); return false;">

        <input type="text" name="test1" id="test1">

        <select id="test2" name="test2">
            <option value="">Make a choice ...</option>
            <option value="c1">choice 1</option>
            <option value="c2">choice 2</option>
            <option value="c3">choice 3</option>
        </select>    

        <input type="submit" value="Search">

        </form>

        <div id="here"><b></b></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Than in your `info.php` file do this to grab the variables sent via `Ajax`,

```
<?php
    $test1 = $_POST["test1"];
    $test2 = $_POST["test2"];

    echo "Test1: ".$test1."<br/>Test2: ".$test2."";
?>
```

Comment: Thank you it works, however if I want more than two values, how do it write it, it keeps outputing weird things ? var data = "test1="+document.getElementById("test1").value+"&test2="+document.getElementById("test2").value+"&test3="+document.getElementById("test3").value;

Comment: You just append the more values like this `var data = "test1="+document.getElementById("test1").value+"&test2="+document.getElementById("test2").value+"&test3="+document.getElementById("test3").value+"&test4="+document.getElementById("test4").value;`

Answer (score 0):

The reason it doesn't pull both values is because 1) you need to add a method to your form. You can either do post or get, not both.2) In your php you define test 1 as from the get array and variable 2 as from the post array. If you make $test2 from the get array it should work.